# Jquery - multi-step form progress bar using unordered list items to show completed steps

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I am trying to build a multi-step form with JQuery and I am having some problems with my progress bar.

My Progress bar is an unordered list with list items that are supposed to be highlighted red when the user presses next. But, when they press previous the list item should lose the highlighted red. I am very close to the solution. I have the first two options working, but when I go to last step I am not seeing any highlighting.

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ktLcfzhe/

JQuery:
        $(document).ready(function () {

```
    var current_fs = $('.current'); //current fieldset   

    $('.next').click(function () {
        $('.current').removeClass('current').hide().next().show().addClass('current');


        if ($(this).parent('.field1')) {
            $('#progressbar li').next('.second').addClass('active');
        } else if ($(this).parent('.field2')) {
            $('#progressbar li').next('.last').addClass('active');
        } else if ($(this).parent('.field3')) {
            $('#progressbar li').addClass('active');
        }

    });

    $('.previous').click(function () {
        $('.current').removeClass('current').hide().prev().show().addClass('current');

        if ($(this).parent('.field3')) {
            $('#progressbar li').prev('.last').removeClass('active');
        } else if ($(this).parent('.field2')) {
            $('#progressbar li').prev('.second').removeClass('active');
        }


    });

});
```

HTML:

```
<form id="helpdeskform" action="process.php" method="post">
    <!-- Progress Bar -->
    <ul id="progressbar">
        <li class="active first">Identify Yourself</li>
        <li class="second">Describe Request</li>
        <li class="last">Confirm and Submit</li>
    </ul>
    <fieldset class="field1 current">
            <h2>Identify Yourself</h2>

        <p>
            <label for="fname">
                <input type="text" value="" name="" id="" placeholder="First Name" />
            </label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="lname">
                <input type="text" value="" name="" id="" placeholder="Last Name" />
            </label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="Next">
                <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
            </label>
        </p>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="field2">
            <h2>Describe Request</h2>

        <p>
            <label for="">
                <input type="text" value="" name="" id="" placeholder="Subject" />
            </label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="">
                <textarea style="font-family: Arial, Veranda, Sans serif" name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
            </label>
        </p>
        <p style="float:left;">
            <label for="previous">
                <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
            </label>
        </p>
        <p style="float:left; padding-left: 10px;">
            <label for="Next">
                <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
            </label>
        </p>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="field3">
            <h2>Confirm and Submit</h2>

        <p>
            <label for="fname">
                <input type="text" value="" name="" id="" placeholder="" />
            </label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="">
                <input type="text" value="" name="" id="" placeholder="" />
            </label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="">
                <input type="text" value="" name="" id="" placeholder="" />
            </label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="">
                <input type="text" value="" name="" id="" placeholder="" />
            </label>
        </p>
        <p style="float:left;">
            <label for="previous">
                <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
            </label>
        </p>
        <p style="float:left; padding-left: 10px;">
            <label for="Submit">
                <input type="button" value="Submit" name="submit" id="submit" />
            </label>
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
/*form styles*/
 #helpdeskform {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
/*Hide all except first fieldset*/
 #helpdeskform .field2, .field3 {
    display: none;
}
/*inputs*/
 #helpdeskform input, #helpdeskform textarea {
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #2C3E50;
    font-size: 13px;
}
/*buttons*/
 #helpdeskform .action-button {
    width: 100px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    margin: 10px 5px;
}
#helpdeskform .action-button:hover, #msform .action-button:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #900;
}
/*progressbar*/
 #progressbar {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    counter-reset: step;
    /*CSS counters to number the steps*/
}
#progressbar li {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 10px;
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
#progressbar li:before {
    content: counter(step);
    counter-increment: step;
    width: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #333;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
}
/*progressbar connectors*/
 #progressbar li:after {
    content:'';
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    left: -50%;
    top: 9px;
    z-index: -1;
    /*put it behind the numbers*/
}
#progressbar li:first-child:after {
    content: none;
    /*connector not needed before the first step*/
}
/*marking active/completed steps nhlbi red*/

/*The number of the step and the connector before it = red*/
 #progressbar li.active:before, #progressbar li.active:after {
    background: #900;
    color: white;
}
```

All comments are appreciated. I used http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/jquery-multi-step-form-with-progress-bar as a guide to this form. There JQuery was too complex for me.

Comment: Seems overly complicated. Rather than keeping track of who has or doesn't have an '.active' class, I would remove it globally from the list, and then addClass() where needed at the current time.

Comment: So in playing with the JSFiddle, it looks like when I click "next" on the first page and get to "Describe your request," all three bars fill up.

Comment: In fact, I did this just this morning.  Seems very similar.

$('li', $progressMeter).removeClass('active done');

$('#step2', $progressMeter).addClass('active').prevAll().addClass('done')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are a working example http://jsfiddle.net/ktLcfzhe/1/

jQuery

```
$('.next').click(function () {
    $('.current').removeClass('current').hide().next().show().addClass('current');
    $('#progressbar li.active').next().addClass('active');

});

$('.previous').click(function () {
    $('.current').removeClass('current').hide().prev().show().addClass('current');
    $('#progressbar li.active').removeClass('active').prev().addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your fix: http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/ktLcfzhe/2/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.next').click(function () {
        $('.current').removeClass('current').hide().next().show().addClass('current');
        $('#progressbar li.active').next().addClass('active');
        if ($('#progress')) {};

    });

    $('.previous').click(function () {
        $('.current').removeClass('current').hide().prev().show().addClass('current');
        $('#progressbar li.active').removeClass('active').prev().addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would handle it by adding a class at a higher level describing which step the user is at.

Start with a class "step-one" on #progressbar. When a user clicks next, add a class called "step-two" (don't remove "step-one"). When they click next again, add a third class "step-three".

Then in your CSS, use rules like:

```
#progressbar.step-one .first {
  //show me highlighted
}
#progressbar.step-two .second {
  //show me highlighted
}
#progressbar.step-three .third {
  //show me highlighted
}
```

You can handle all of this in one on-click event if you give the next buttons an ID that is the class you want applied to the progress bar.

e.g. if the first next button looks like this:

```
<label for="Next">
  <input id="go-to-step-two" type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
</label>
```

Then your JavaScript might look like this:

```
$('.next').click(function(e) {
    var currentPage = this.attr('id').replace('go-to-', ''); //e.g. 'step-two'
    $('#progressbar').class(currentPage);
});
```

Use the same logic for the back buttons, just removing the class based on the id of the back button.

Hope that helps.